# Get list of Conversations / Threads based on Date Filter?

Tags: yammer

We are using Yammer Feed on our SharePoint Site. I would like to get the list of all Conversations / Threads that falls within a specific date. For example, threads that fall within the last 7 days / last 30 days.

I am browsing the Yammer API, but can't see method to call. Is it possible? If so, can help point me in the right direction which REST endpoint to call?

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

It isn't possible to do this with the REST APIs due to how feeds operate in Yammer. This isn't something that's done in the product and the APIs operate based on cursors. If you want to query for messages in this way you'd need to use the [Data Export API](https://developer.yammer.com/docs/data-export-api) to main your own repository of the data which would permit queries like this.

Comment: Thanks Brian. Another work around we thought of is make use of pagination; since we don't need all of it, we can get 20 then continuously check the date until the next batch has a date that does not fall within the filter.